# Java 8. Difference between collection.stream() and Stream.of(collection)

Tags: java, java-stream

Could you please explain it to me?
Why

```
Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->x.stream()).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
```

and

```
Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->Stream.of(x)).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
```

are different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Stream` does not have a `Stream.of(Collection)` method. It does have a method

```
static <T> Stream<T> of(T t)
```

If you pass a `Collection` to this method you'll get a `Stream<Collection>` containing one element (the `Collection`), not a stream of the collection's elements.

As an example, try this:

```
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->x.stream()).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->Stream.of(x)).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
```

The first version prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

The second version prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Note that if `arr` is an `Object[]` you *can* do `Stream.of(arr)` to get a stream of the array's elements. This is because there is another version of `of` that uses varargs.

```
static <T> Stream<T> of(T... values)
```

Comment: Found out that it's actually possible to use an array in `Stream.of` to create a stream of the array's elements

Comment: @AlexeyGalanov That's true. If `arr` is an `Object[]` you can do `Arrays.stream(arr)` or `Stream.of(arr)`. They both do the same thing. You can't do `arr.stream()` though, so in your question `l1` and `l2` had to be collections, not arrays.